# Difference between VS Code IDE and Leetcode editor

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code

Why is it that certain expressions in VS Code result in different outputs than in Leetcode's built in editor? I was working through a "Reverse Linked List" question when I noticed that a solution accepted by Leetcode does not reverse the linked list if you copy/paste the solution into VS Code.

Question: https://leetcode.com/problems/reverse-linked-list/

```js
const reverseList = (head) => {
  let prev = null;
  let curr = head;
  console.log(head.next); 
  // DIFFERENCE: (with the line above)
  // equals the "head" array with the first value removed in LC editor 
  // equals null in VScode
  while (curr) {
    const next = curr.next;
    curr.next = prev;
    prev = curr;
    curr = next;
  }
  return prev;
};
console.log(reverseList([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]));
```

Comment: You're passing an array, not a linked list.

Comment: I'm aware of that, yeah. It's the input Leetcode asks you to put through your function

Comment: @Jason2B3 There's no way passing in an array to that function would work. The JSDoc explicitly states `head` is a `ListNode`, not an array, and implies it's the head node via naming. You may be confusing pseudo-code notation (or a `toString` output) for the explicit parameter.

Comment: I think what you're referring to, e.g. `head = [1,2,3,4,5]`, are array representations of a linked list. The actual linked list will comprise ListNode elements, linked together.

Comment: Oh so you're saying Leetcode actually has a linked list prepared and passes that to the function that we're supposed to come up with? And they only provide an array representation

Comment: Basically, yes. The template JavaScript solution shows you the ListNode specification - it has `val` and `next` attributes. You would use that in your code. Their test sends your function a number of pre-created linked lists conformant with that specification. Also note that your function must return a ListNode, representing the head of the reversed list.

Comment: @Jason2B3 The top of the page says "Given the head of a singly linked list, reverse the list, and return the reversed list."

Comment: @jarmod That explains everything, thanks! Do you think buying LC premium would be worth it to solve problems like these using their debugger? I'm thinking about how solving more complex problems would become a hassle since my IDE doesn't have access to these premade linked lists

Comment: You could cut-and-paste `ListNode`, it's in the comment of the boilerplate code. Constructing a list is reasonably straight-forward.